# Cannot log in in to my site

Tags: redirection, users

I am having some problems when I try to log in to my drupal site. When I visit http://mysite/user, i am getting redirect to the login page and in my url appears something like this:

user?name=user&pass=111111&form_build_id=form-iCrzIe6KBq1g5MoA3z0JeBI98QU8q2f-FvfcIcp3Cvk&form_id=user_login&op=Log+in

I'm trying to find the problem, but I don't know what to do.

When i restore the site(from my last backup) i can do the login, but when i restart my machine, the problem comes back.

I hope you could give me a hand with this problem.

Regards

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  Where is your site hosted?

Comment: This is not the normal behavior shown by Drupal. Knowing the modules you installed would probably help.

Comment: I had similar problems and it was my "Logintoboggan" try disabling modules you suspect and watch your dblogs

Answer (score 2):

I would check /sites/default/settings.php and look into your `$cookie_domain =` setting - does it match your domain?